# Proof using GCD

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume all variables are integers greater than 1.

Suppose $y = k x$ and $k \neq x$. Suppose that $z\lt k$ and $\gcd(k, z) \gt 1$.

Does this imply $\gcd(z, x) \lt x$?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Take for example $k=8$, $x=2$, and $z=4$.